# Can't change permissions for header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my official WordPress forum support plea: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/headerphp-is-not-updating?replies=4

I changed all the permissions via FTP, currently set to 777. Originally 666, but that didn't work, so here we are.

I cleared all of my browser caches.

I added the following line to wp-config.php:

```
define('DISABLE_CACHE', true);
```

I don't know what else to do at this point. The file on my server reflects the changes I made, but if you look at the source on the website, via Firebug or whatever, it isn't there.

From the native WordPress editor, it says I can't edit the file because the permissions aren't set. What's really absurd is that this is a custom theme specifically for this website. Whose business is it if I want to change it?

Can anyone please at least verify that the correct 'header.php' is in wp-content/themes/themeofchoice?

EDIT: I don't know what happened but suddenly my changes have taken effect. I guess Wordpress takes hours to update .php files? WOW.

Thank you for your answers everybody. If anyone has similar problems, I guess take the same steps I did. If anything changed, I continued to change the permissions of all the parent folders as was suggested.

Comment: check the parent folder permissions and owner. Also, if you are changing it to the child theme or the main theme.

Comment: If your host is Windows, then `chmod` permissions have no meaning, you have to deal with NTFS ACLs (which you can't do over FTP, you need either direct Telnet or RDP access, or ask your host to fix them for you).

Comment: »the correct 'header.php' is in wp-content/themes/themeofchoice?« If "themeofchoice" is activated…

Comment: i've had web hosts change/add .htaccess files, maybe check that just to be sure